# Issue with IE in selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a mouse-over issue in IE using webdriver code, it is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but the mouseover issue occurs only in IE. How can I solve this? Firstly focus on an element and next the I will click on the link, please see below code,

```
WebElement newbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/span/form[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/ul/span/li"));    
Actions action = new Actions(driver);    
action.moveToElement(newbutton).build().perform();    
WebElement nextButton=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='menuFmId:headerForm:j_id130']/li/span"));

Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);
action1.moveToElement(nextButton).click(nextButton).build().perform();
```

Comment: please post your HTML code so that people would get a better understanding where issue is, as you are using absolute xpath in the first button may be in IE its not detecting it, have to look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same sort of problems a lot many time, since I have to mostly work on IE. The pages behave quite unexpectedly on IE. After putting a lot of time trying to search for a traditional method to achieve hovering in IE, I ended up using Javascript.

```
public void mouseHoverJScript(WebElement HoverElement) {
        String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript, HoverElement);
    }
```

I understand that it's not recommended but at least I got unblocked and my job was done.